# Chrome Dev Tools - write events to the Timeline

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-devtools

I'm debugging the load times of a page and started using the Timeline feature of Chrome Dev Tools.

What I would like to do is modify my javascript library so that I could write some "events" to the timeline so I could know at what time, the code hit a certain line.  But I can see that the timeline only records "real" events: http requests, script evaluations, paint events..

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Use `console.timeStamp('whatever');`

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consoletimestamplabel

Comment: w00t this looks promising. I'll try this ASAP